# Print values of TABLE OF RECORDS TYPE without knowing the COLUMN NAMES of record

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections, nested-table, utl-file

I have created a Procedure which uses a View to PRINT (into CSV ) , all the records of that view.
**Any user can drop and recreate that view , so its column structure can change**

Is there any way to FETCH all records of VIEW into a collection
and PRINT elements of that collection without knowing ALL COLUMN NAMES/ without any dependency on columns.

*If there is any way, then it can be used when our table has hundreds of columns too.*
**THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN ASKED TO ME MANY TIMES but I cannot find the answer to it and now i have to edit my procedure every time i need to spool a different table into csv file**

The code I use normally for spooling takes all the column names:-

```
cursor c1 is
select * 
from table1 nvr;
  
TYPE alldata_typ IS table of c1%rowtype;
    v_dta       alldata_typ;
  
BEGIN
  
  v_fname  := 'swe_WRF_.csv';

    v_file   := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('CDMP_OUT_DIR', v_fname, 'W');

    v_header :=  'FSA_CODE,FSA_NAME,PROVINCE,MAKE,SERIES,REPORT_YEAR,VEHICLE_COUNT';

    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_file, v_header);
  
  OPEN c1;
  loop
    FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT

     INTO v_dta LIMIT v_fetch_limit;

     exit when v_dta.count=0 ;

     
    FOR i IN 1..v_dta.count 
    LOOP

        UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_file, 
                            v_dta(i).fsa_code ||', '||
                            v_dta(i).fsa_name ||', '||
                            v_dta(i).province ||', '||
                            v_dta(i).make ||', '||
                            v_dta(i).series ||', '||
                            v_dta(i).report_year ||','||
                            v_dta(i).vehicle_count
                            );

        v_count := v_count + 1;
end loop;
;
```

Comment: Check this, https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=export-to-csv. much better one from our AskTom :) . In fact we can still modify your procedure but i would suggest to go with the way from AskTom. cheers!!

Comment: Simplest solution: use the [CSV Export capability built into Oracle SQL Developer](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/05/formatting-query-results-to-csv-in-oracle-sql-developer/).

Comment: @apc CSV facility takes a lot of time in case of million records and is not a feasible solution therefore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use dynamic SQL to generate all column to csv.
I rewrited your code as below. Hope it useful for you.

```
declare
  v_cmd        varchar(4000);
  c1           SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_tab_name   varchar2(100) := upper('TABLE_NAME');
  v_owner_name varchar2(100) := upper('OWNER_NAME');
  type record_type is record(
    line_data varchar2(4000));
  TYPE alldata_typ IS table of record_type;
  v_dta         alldata_typ;
  v_fname       varchar2(20);
  V_HEADER      varchar2(20);
  V_FETCH_LIMIT integer := 100;
  V_COUNT       integer;
BEGIN

  v_fname := 'swe_WRF_.csv';

  v_file   := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('CDMP_OUT_DIR', v_fname, 'W');

  select listagg(COLUMN_NAME, ',') within group(order by COLUMN_ID)
    into v_header --create header with all column
    from all_tab_columns
   where table_name = v_tab_name
     and OWNER = v_owner_name;

  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_file, v_header);

  select 'select ' || listagg(COLUMN_NAME, '||'', ''||') within group(order by COLUMN_ID) || ' as line_data from ' || v_tab_name
    into v_cmd --generate select statement
    from all_tab_columns
   where table_name = v_tab_name
     and OWNER = v_owner_name;

  OPEN c1 for v_cmd;
  loop
    FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT
    
      INTO v_dta LIMIT v_fetch_limit;
  
    exit when v_dta.count = 0;
  
    FOR i IN 1 .. v_dta.count LOOP
    
      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_file, 
                          v_dta(i).line_data
                         );
      --dbms_output.put_line(v_dta(i).line_data);
      v_count := v_count + 1;
    end loop;
  END LOOP;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using UTL_FILE, then you are writing the file out on the database server. If it just CSV you are after, then you can run SQL*Plus commands *directly* from the database by using the scheduler.

More details here https://connor-mcdonald.com/2018/06/20/the-death-of-utl_file/

but in essence, the scheduler can run a SQL*Plus session, which also has support for a CSV markup on the output. It will probably be a lot quicker than UTL_FILE for larger data volumes.

Comment: thanks for solution but i dont hv these privileges :P